# Is it possible to have multiple default values in a Wagtail Streamfield?

Tags: wagtail, wagtail-streamfield

i Am trying to make wagtail create multiple listing in a streamfield on create new page and give a default value to each listing. The values are passed in a list of dictionarys.

`

```
    fasiliteter = StreamField([
        ('faselitet', blocks.StructBlock([
        ('type', blocks.CharBlock()),
        ('ink', blocks.BooleanBlock())
        ], 
        default = [
                    {"type" : "Ting", "ink" : True},
                    {"type" : "TAng", "ink" : False}
                    ]
        )),
        ], use_json_field=True)
```

`

Can someone help me if this is possible?

I tried with lists and min number and so on

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible, but a couple of things to note:

- You need to set the `default` argument on the StreamField, not the block, because you're specifying an initial value for the stream as a whole. A `default` value set on StructBlock means "set this as the initial value whenever you insert a new block of this type" - obviously, a newly-inserted block can only have a single value.
- The `default` argument needs to be passed as a list of (block_type, value) tuples - this is because there could potentially be more than one top-level block type to choose from (rather than just the single 'faselitet' block defined in your field), and in that case StreamField cannot know which block type is intended just by looking at the value.

Your definition would become:

```
fasiliteter = StreamField(
    [
        ('faselitet', blocks.StructBlock([
            ('type', blocks.CharBlock()),
            ('ink', blocks.BooleanBlock())
        ])),
    ],
    default=[
        ("faselitet", {"type" : "Ting", "ink" : True}),
        ("faselitet", {"type" : "TAng", "ink" : False}),
    ],
    use_json_field=True
)
```